# Secure TCP based protocol through an application layer firewall

Tags: networking, firewall, tcp

I have two networks, one considered secure, lets call it `A` and one considered insecure, `B`. The software I need to use, uses [HSMS](http://www.sematech.org/docubase/document/2974atr.pdf), a protocol based on TCP with no security built in.
Now the problem is that the software has a server `a` in the secure network `A` and needs to connect to clients `b1, b2, ...` in `B`. The requirement from the software is that I open one port with full TCP access. But that is too risky as the whole network `B` and the clients can not be trusted.

My question now is, is there a way to use something like an application layer firewall to filter everything based on the protocol so that the open port is not used for anything else.
Especially is there a simple, read not too involved, way to create a protocol filter for HSMS in such a firewall.

Another requirement is that the clients are not allowed to talk to each other through that proxy.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with making a firewall only allow connections to server `a` on port `p` in the firewall?  The port can't be used to connect to any other systems in network `A`; since the server on `a` is expecting that particular protocol, non-compliant clients won't be able to connect; and if you're really worried you can whitelist clients on the firewall so that only clients `b1, b2, ...` in `B` can connect to `a`.

Other options include VPN setups or SSH tunneling.

> Another requirement is that the clients are not allowed to talk to each other through that proxy.

In a sane configuration, that's not going to be the case anyway.  Beyond that, how do you intend to prevent clients from connecting to each other?

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. I can't trust the clients. I need to be able to control what content, read only hsms compliant data, is sent to the server `a` otherwise other programs on the clients could hijack the tcp connection. So if I only proxy the clients can still use to complete tcp connection.

Comment: Generally speaking servers already don't trust clients when it comes to the internet.  What can other programs running on the clients do that a proxy is going to prevent?  They can't talk to other servers in `A`, they can't talk to other services on `a`, so the only thing left is if they send non-compliant data -- what can a proxy do that the service already in place can't?